# Meteor Up (Mup) deployment error

Tags: meteor, deployment

I am trying to deploy a Meteor project using Mup. Mup Setup worked fine, but when i used the command Mup Deploy i get the following error below:

(Note: I have tried multiple appPaths but i have found no solution)

### Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments

“ Checkout Kadira!
  It's the best way to monitor performance of your app.
  Visit: https://kadira.io/mup ”

Building Started: /srv/asm/

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1011:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:34)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. In order to correct this error i double checked app path:

// Location of app (local directory)
  "app": "/srv/asm/",

and uninstalled Meteor, then reinstalled meteor, then ran mup deploy. All is now working correctly.